# ObjC - Programmatically add label to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, uiscrollview

How do you programmaticaly add labels (or other controls for that matter) to a UIScrollView?

I used this code, but I couldn't scroll. Which leads me to believe that it doesn't add the labels to the UIScrollView.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
{
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, (i * 50), 200, 40)];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myLabel setText:@"Dynamic"];
    [self.Scroller addSubview:myLabel];
}
```

There are no errors, and it does create the labels, but like I said before, without scrolling.

What are we doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.Scroller.frame.size.width, (30 * 50)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
{
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, (i * 50), 200, 40)];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [myLabel setText:@"Dynamic"];
    [self.Scroller addSubview:myLabel];
}



CGSize newContentSize=scroll.contentSize;
newContentSize.height+=30*50;
[self.Scroller setContentSize:newContentSize];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting contentSize for scrollView,Add this line in your loop:-

```
CGSize newContentSize=scroll.contentSize;
newContentSize.height+=i*50;
[self.Scroller setContentSize:newContentSize];
```